# Image Processing - Computing gradients at each pixel?

Tags: image-processing, fingerprint

I was working on a fingerprint recognition project. As a part of an orientation field estimation algorithm the input fingerprint image should be divided into blocks and have to compute gradients at each pixel in each block and my question is how this gradients are calculated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be **more specific** about the **type of gradient**.  *Gradient* can mean one of:

- [Sobel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator) (vertical, horizontal, or combined)
- [Laplacian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator)
- Approximations/alternatives to the above (e.g. [Scharr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator#Scharr_operator))

From looking at your vague question, it sounds like you haven't really tried to understand your problem sufficiently.  I suggest that you start by taking a look at the corresponding [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_gradient#Computer_vision), its references and any relevant hits on Google.

Once you've done that, come back and refine your answer -- I'm sure many people will be happy to help you.

Comment: Thanks for responding. One thing i must say that i don't know anything about image processing and i'm trying to an implement algorithm that i have found on some books, which is a part of fingerprint recognition process (Orientation field estimation). The algorithm just says **Compute the gradients Gx and Gy at each pixel in each block**. I think i have to go with Sobel operator for calculating gradient of pixels. Can you please explain about that? Please correct me if anything wrong.

Comment: There's nothing I can explain to you better than a good image processing textbook (or Wikipedia, if that's all you have) can.  I've given you places to start -- did you read and understand the links in my answer?

Answer (score 1):

The answer according to comment info "Compute the gradients Gx and Gy at each pixel in each block" is:

Use the Sobel operators as described on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator#Formulation) as Gx and Gy made from source A. Then the pixel [x,y] has gradient vector (Gx[x,y], Gy[x,y]).