# Gradient of a block of pixel

Tags: image-processing

I am reading some articles about image orientation estimation and it say that I will have to calculate gradient magnitude of a block w x w. The equation is like this:

```
(1)
Vx(i,j) = Σ[u = i-w/2... i+w/2] Σ[v = i-w/2... i+w/2] 2dx(u,v)dy(u,v)           

(2)
Vy(i,j) = Σ[u = i-w/2... i+w/2] Σ[v = i-w/2... i+w/2] d^2x(u,v)d^2y(u,v)
```

I have try to find the way to calculate the gradient of pixel (dx, dy) and find one:

```
(3)
dx = 1/2 * ( I(x+1, y) - I(x-1, y) )

(4)
dy = 1/2 * ( I(x, y+1) - I(x, y-1) )
```

My question is are (1), (2), (3), (4) correct (or can you recommend the correct equation)? And are they the method that my article about image orientation estimation recommend. I have read this [Image Processing - Computing gradients at each pixel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4977974/image-processing-computing-gradients-at-each-pixel). I only see that Sobel is 3x3 matrix, what if I am using a block with w > 3 or how to use a mask 3x3 to 16x16 block of pixel. I only need a precisely equation for implement that article method, so reading a book about image processing is my last choice, especially because I will have to read from the beginning to the end ( I have buy one and skimming the table of content not help - I cannot understand what the headings say and now reading chap 01 -_- )
Thanks for reading this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the right equation. Here it is, please note that (2) have 1 more minus

```
(1)
Vx(i,j) = Σ[u = i-w/2... i+w/2] Σ[v = i-w/2... i+w/2] 2dx(u,v)dy(u,v)           

(2)
Vy(i,j) = Σ[u = i-w/2... i+w/2] Σ[v = i-w/2... i+w/2] d^2x(u,v) - d^2y(u,v)
```

(3), (4) is a little right cause it is also an option in matlab to calculate gradient but Sobel operator is preferred.